# Relationships - accessing children elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a simple inventory management system.  A class product has_many variants, and the variants belong_to a product and therefore have a product_id, along with a name and a quantity.  When the user creates the product, I have the product generate 11 different variants (just with numerical values) by calling the following

```
Located in variants.rb (model)

  def self.create_multiple_variants( product_id )
    p = Product.find(product_id)
    i = 11
    while i <= 21
      new_variant = Variants.create
      new_variant.product = p
      new_variant.name = (i*2)
      new_variant.qty = 0
      i += 1
    end
  end
```

Then when the user tries to show the page, the program will go through each variant belonging to the product and see if their is any quantity (which the admin adjusts along the way) like so:

Located in the view:

```
<div class="size"><br/>Size: <%= f.select(:size, @sizes_availiable, :prompt => "Select a Size...")
```

Located in product_controller:

```
@sizes_availiable = Variants.create_inventory_array( @product.id )
```

Located in variants.rb (model)

```
  def self.create_inventory_array( product_id )
    p = Product.find(product_id)
    a = []
    p.variants.each do |v|
      a << variant.name if variant.qty > 0
    end
    a
  end
```

I know with the naming it is a little confusing, as I am setting it up as something bigger but deprecating it for now, so sorry of thats a little confusing.  For now you can think of variant as "size"

But the creation portion of it works fine, however when I go to show the product I get this message:

> NameError in ProductController#show
>
> app/models/variants.rb:20:in `create_inventory_array'
>   app/controllers/product_controller.rb:18:in`show'

I assume that the way I am building the relationship is the source of the problem, either that or how I am calling it.  Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:

I used the suggestions below, and it seems that now the problem lies in the second function.  Here is my new variants.rb and the error I get:

```
class Variants < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :name, :qty
  belongs_to :product

  def self.create_multiple_variants( product_id )
    p = Product.find(product_id)
    for i in 11..21
      v = Variants.create
      v.product = p
      v.name = (i*2)
      v.qty = 0
      v.save!
    end
  end

  def self.create_inventory_array( product_id )
    p = Product.find(product_id)
    a = []
    p.variants.each do |variant|
      a << variant.name if variant.qty > 0
    end
    a
  end
end



 NoMethodError in ProductController#create

 undefined method `Variants' for #<Product:0x007fe9561ad550>

 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
 app/models/variants.rb:8:in `block in create_multiple_variants'
 app/models/variants.rb:7:in `each' app/models/variants.rb:7:in
 `create_multiple_variants' app/controllers/product_controller.rb:33:in
 `create
```

I still believe it's an issue with how the relationship is being build (I'm assigning variants.product = current_product, yet I call product.variants - I feel like the relationship is not being built both ways)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to save the object.

To save it at the end of your loop:

```
new_variant.save!
```

Sidenote about this loop:

```
i = 11
while i <= 21
  ...
  i += 1
end
```

This is a better way to write it because it's clearer:

```
for i in 11..21 do
  ...
end
```

And for blocks like this:

```
 new_variant = Variants.create
 new_variant.product = p
 new_variant.name = (i*2)
 new_variant.qty = 0
 new_variant.save!
```

Make it easier to read:

```
 v = Variants.create
 v.product = p
 v.name = i*2
 v.qty = 0
 v.save!
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the for loop and adding the save made it get passed the first function, and replacing new variant with v does make it look a lot cleaner.  However I'm still no sure that the association is being built correctly, take a look at the edit that I'm putting in the original post

Comment: You'll get the best answers if you close this question as solved, and open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this code:

```
p.variants.each do |v|
  a << variant.name if variant.qty > 0
end
```

you pass in the variable `v` but refer to it as `variant`. To fix it change the line to

```
p.variants.each do |variant|
```

---

Also read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions you could make the code a lot more elegant by querying the variants for desired product_id and qty, and then calling map to get the names only.

---

Also this can be improved:

```
new_variant = Variants.create
new_variant.product = p
new_variant.name = (i*2)
new_variant.qty = 0
```

to

```
new_variant = p.variants.create name: "#{i*2}", qty: 0
```

Comment: Nice catch!  However, the relationship i beleive is still not being created correctly.  I'm using the method that joelparkerhenderson suggested, as your second suggestion (new_variant = p.variants.create name: "#{i*2}", qty: 0) is still giving me the name error.

Comment: You need to add `has_many :variants` to the Product class in product.rb

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong - my model is Variants.rb (with an s) which at some point caused a problem.  I renamed the file variants.rb as well as the class name Variants to variant.rb and Variant respectivly, restarted the server, and it worked!  Thanks to those who helped!